# Cannot find EmailTemplate folder in metadata - is it not possible to create EmailTemplate folders through ant?

Tags: deployment, email-template, folder

I'm running an ant deploy, it's failing on this:

```
All Component Failures:
1.  email/Consumer_AliX/AE002_Service_Request_Confirmation.email -- Error: Cannot find folder:Consumer_AliX
2.  email/Consumer_AliX/AE004_Service_Request_Denied.email -- Error: Cannot find folder:Consumer_AliX
3.  email/Consumer_AliX/AE003_Service_Request_Approved.email -- Error: Cannot find folder:Consumer_AliX
4. ....plus other dependency errors cascading from the first three...
```

I added the templates with the folder path to package.xml (as I know EmailTemplate doesn't support the wildcard selector).

**Here is the relevant package.xml:**

```
<members>Consumer_AliX/AE002_Service_Request_Confirmation</members>
<members>Consumer_AliX/AE003_Service_Request_Approved</members>
<members>Consumer_AliX/AE004_Service_Request_Denied</members>
<name>EmailTemplate</name>
```

**Here's the meta for the folder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmailFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <accessType>Public</accessType>
    <name>Consumer - AliX</name>
    <publicFolderAccess>ReadOnly</publicFolderAccess>
</EmailFolder>
```

**And here's visual evidence that the folder exists in the same directory as the meta file:**

[image]

What am I overlooking here - why can't the deployment find the folder? Is this something that must be done manually in the destination org?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this as part of the deployment, you simply need to include the folder by itself as a deployment item.

```
<types>
    <members>Consumer_AliX</members>
    <members>Consumer_AliX/AE002_Service_Request_Confirmation</members>
    <members>Consumer_AliX/AE003_Service_Request_Approved</members>
    <members>Consumer_AliX/AE004_Service_Request_Denied</members>
    <name>EmailTemplate</name>
</types>
```

Comment: @KiranMachhewar Sure, view the [Folder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_folder.htm) documentation for how folders operate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create *YourFolderName*.emailFolder-meta.xml inside email folder and inside this file insert this configuration:

```
<EmailFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <accessType>Public</accessType>
    <name>FolderLabel</name>
    <publicFolderAccess>ReadWrite</publicFolderAccess>
</EmailFolder>
```

And in package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>MyFolderExample</members>
    <members>MyFolderExample/EmailTemplateExample</members>
    <name>EmailTemplate</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the metadata file name should be Consumer_AliX.emailFolder-meta.xml